# Simple Form Association with Text Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app that is using the [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).  I have two models that are related, trades and stocks.  In the form for trades, I want users to be able to enter their stock ticker symbol in a text field.  Currently, I'm using the association function which renders a select box.  The problem is that I want a text field instead since I have about a thousand stocks to choose from.

Is there a way I can do this (with or without Simple Form)?

**the models:**

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :stock
end

class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trades
end
```

**the form on trades#new**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@trade)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :stock %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use this syntax:

```
 <%= f.input :stock_id, :label => 'Enter your ticker:' %>
```

The problem here is that the user will not know what :stock_id is, as it's a reference to one of your many Stock objects.

So you probably want to implement a simple [jquery autocomplete interface](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) that returns a list of stocks like so:

```
[{:ticker => 'AAPL', :name => 'Apple Inc', :id => 1}, {:ticker => 'IBM', :name => 'International Business Machines', :id => 2}, etc ]
```

You can then display something like this as autocomplete results:

```
AAPL - Apple Inc
IBM - International Business Machines
```

and allow the user to select the one they are looking for.  Behind the scenes you capture the :id and use that as your associated :stock_id.

You will need to add a stocks_controller action that takes a string and looks up Stocks based on a partial ticker and returns a max-number of stocks like 20.

```
def search
  ticker_query = "%#{params[:ticker]}%"
  stocks = Stock.where('ticker LIKE ?', ticker_query).limit(20)
  render :json => stocks
end
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I did try something like this [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756705/rails-hashwithindifferentaccess-error), but i couldn't get it to work.  Building off the code you provided, I put this ` <%= f.input :stock_id, :label => 'Enter your ticker:' %>` in my form, but I wasn't sure about how to connect that to stocks#search and autocomplete.  Thanks Matt.

Comment: I'll follow up tonight with more details.